# queries executed under a transaction

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We are using python snowflake connector to execute queries. We recently made code changes to encapsulate few queries to execute under a single transaction. As part of the testing, we want to make sure those queries are all executed under a single transaction. We've checked under history tab. We just see the queriy id, sql text, session id and other non-transactional details.

Is there any way to know the list of queries executed under a transaction? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/show-transactions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just make sure that the queries are running within the same Session and that you've started the transaction by issuing a `begin` statement in the first query.

Once you've done that you can run the `select current_transaction();` and print it to the screen at the beginning and the end of your python script to debug check if the transaction IDs are the same.

Alternatively you should be able to use a python context manager as in [this example](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#using-context-manager-to-connect-and-control-transactions) from the Snowflake documentation to manage the transaction. Just makes sure you set the connection parameter `autocommit = False`

Comment: Just curious as to what exactly marks the beginning of the transaction when you use python context manager. I've read through documentation, but its not quite obvious for me.

Comment: A connection to Snowflake is opened while you're using the context manager. The first statement you run begins the transaction - I've just tested this an it works fine with autcommit = False.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python connector, you could leverage the query_tag to "mark" a transaction within a session.  You'd just need to set the value at the beginning and end of your transaction.  This would allow you to query for a specific query_tag in query_history, or maybe group statements to report on duration or other properties.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#setting-session-parameters

Comment: But query_tag is a session level parameter and a session can have multiple transactions. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but not at the same time.  A session can only run 1 query at a time, so as long as you set the session parameter at the beginning of each transaction, it'll only be tagged on the statements of that session.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that provides transaction information. At this point you're best bet to log the information yourself.